# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 - vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the flutter package example 'Image Editor Pro', but when I run debugging it gives me this error, I tried 'flutter clean' and upgrade everything, but the problem still exists . i added some things to the original code to be compatible with the null-safety update , but nothing else

```
Launching lib/main.dart on SM G970U1 in debug mode...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
: Error: The argument type 'PointerEvent' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PointerDownEvent'.
- 'PointerEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/events.dart' ('../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
- 'PointerDownEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/events.dart' ('../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
    super.addAllowedPointer(event);
                            ^

: Error: The getter 'body2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body2'.
            themeData.primaryTextTheme.body2)
                                       ^^^^^
: Error: The getter 'body2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body2'.

            themeData.primaryTextTheme.body2)
                                       ^^^^^
: Error: The getter 'body2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body2'.
        themeData.primaryTextTheme.body2.color;
                                   ^^^^^

: Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    super.addToScene(builder, layerOffset);
                    ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/criuser/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/criuser/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal in android directory of your project.
Try to clean and rebuild gradle using these commands: (on windows)

```
Gradlew clean
```

And then:

```
Gradlew build
```

In case you are using mac or linux:

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build
```

Comment: Gradlew:: command not found
I'm using Ubuntu BTW

Comment: I've updated my answer for Linux.

Comment: Thanks , but when i tried building , it gave me this error 
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/criuser/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/criuser/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
`

Comment: Delete your pubspec.lock, and press 'Pub Get' in your pubspec.yaml, it'll regenerate pubspec.lock file again and should fix the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by press 'Pub Get ' I can't find it?

Comment: Simply running "flutter pub get" in terminal when you are in project directory.

Comment: ok , so i did that , then tried building again , same error !!

Comment: this is the rest of the error , sorry I didn't post it earlier due to character limit 'Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
'

Comment: Maybe updating gadle wrapper version helps. It's located in android directory.

Comment: And another point, is this error only on Android? Cause it should not be corrupted on other platforms if gradle clean and build helps.

Comment: it's corrupted on chrome as well

Comment: User this command  : flutter pub cache repair   and  flutter clean and then flutter pub get and try again

Comment: I had to delete 'body2' from class 'TextTheme' , then update kotlin version in build.gradle , now it works